# Check if some of items exists on MySQL set list

Tags: mysql

I need check if some of items (separated by comma) exists on some cell (that is a `SET` type). For instance:

```
id | certifications
1  | a,b,c
2  | b,c
3  | a,c
4  | c
5  | NULL
```

If I search by `a,c` it'll returns:

- row `#1` (`a,b,c` contains first element `a`);
- row `#2` (`b,c` contains second element `c`);
- row `#3` (`a,c` contains first element `a`);
- row `#4` (`c` contains second element `c`).

If I search by `b` it'll returns:

- row `#1` (`a,b,c` contains first element `b`);
- row `#2` (`b,c` contains first element `b`);

If I search by `a,b,c` it'll returns all except row `#5`:

- row `#1` (`a,b,c` contains first element `a`);
- row `#2` (`b,c` contains second element `b`);
- row `#3` (`a,c` contains first element `a`);
- row `#4` (`c` contains third element `c`).

Answer (score 0):

Just [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data and be done with it.

Basically, create a join table id_to_certification

```
id | cert_id
------------
1  | a
1  | b
1  | c
2  | b
2  | c
...
```

Then your query would be something like:

```
SELECT id FROM id_to_certification WHERE cert_id IN ("a", "b") GROUP BY id;
```